# ¿Como puedo guardar una variable desde una tabla dinámica en un procedure en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysqlprocedure

Estoy intentando eliminar los registros de una tabla a partir de un ID desde una tabla dinámica con un procedure, pero me devuelve un error:
**Query 1 ERROR: Undeclared variable: id_dpto**

El *procedure* lo estoy haciendo así:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `empleados_relacionados`(pais_name VARCHAR(2))
BEGIN
DECLARE id_dpto INT DEFAULT 0; 
SET @tabla_relacion = CONCAT("SELECT dpto INTO id_dpto FROM empleados_dptos_", pais_name," ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;");

PREPARE tbr FROM @tabla_relacion;
EXECUTE tbr;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE tbr;

/* Borrar registros de ese departamento */ 
SET @borrar = CONCAT("DELETE FROM dptos_relacion_",pais_name," WHERE dpto = '",id_dpto,"';");
PREPARE borrar FROM @borrar;
EXECUTE borrar;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Al usar una consulta dinámica ([Prepared Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)) la variable `id_dpto` no existe fuera de ese contexto, por ello, al tratar de usar esa variable para construir la consulta dinámica del `DELETE` obtiene el error indicado: `ERROR: Undeclared variable: id_dpto`.

Un par de alternativas:

- Usar una variable definida por el usuario ([User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html)): ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c6ac95662c9b2f4a9ea2c09ba565b24f).
- Ejecutar una única consulta dinámica: ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=08a9916af79dc1d3b65f204062fe4a8a).

Answer (score 0):

Usa una variable de usuario:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `empleados_relacionados`(pais_name VARCHAR(2))
BEGIN
SET @id_dpto = 0; 
SET @tabla_relacion = CONCAT("SELECT dpto INTO @id_dpto FROM empleados_dptos_", pais_name," ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;");

PREPARE tbr FROM @tabla_relacion;
EXECUTE tbr;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE tbr;

/* Borrar registros de ese departamento */ 
SET @borrar = CONCAT("DELETE FROM dptos_relacion_",pais_name," WHERE dpto = ?");
PREPARE borrar FROM @borrar;
EXECUTE borrar USING @id_dpto;
END
```

Aunque el diseño es cuestionable, por -como habrás notado- todo lo que tienes que hacer para un simple DELETE; puedes conseguirlo con una sola sentencia preparada para evitar esa variable fuera de contexto:

```
SET @stmt = CONCAT( 'DELETE dr '
                  , '  FROM dptos_relacion_', pais_name, ' dr'
                  , '    INNER JOIN ( SELECT dr2.id '
                  , '                   FROM dptos_relacion_', pais_name, ' dr2'
                  , '                     INNER JOIN empleados_dptos_', pais_name, ' ed'
                  , '                       ON ed.dpto = dr2.dpto
                                        ORDER BY ed.id DESC
                                        LIMIT 0,1
                                    ) t
                           ON t.id = dr.id '
                  );
PREPARE pstmt FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE pstmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE pstmt;
```